# I need template for my custom taxonomy term

Tags: taxonomy, templates

I created a custom taxonomy slug is 'event_type' and created terms like social, educational and religious. I want to have template page where I can show posts related to these terms. you can say I need to access this url:  http://localhost/test/event_type/social/

How I can create a template for this and for this url too http://localhost/test/event_type/

This taxonomy is related to custom post type named as 'event'

Any help regarding this

Answer (score 3):

I think that what you're looking for is in the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/File%3aTemplate_Hierarchy.png). You should be able to use taxonomy-event_type.php to do exactly what you want with it.

Comment: <?php $terms = get_terms('event_type');
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    echo '<li><a href="'.get_term_link($term->slug, 'event_type').'">'.$term->name.'</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>'; ?>   here is my code from where i am getting the link. but that says nothing found. I created the page you suggested but no nothing found

Comment: What template is it calling?

Answer (score 1):

I used a modified version of Justin Tadlock's code at [his blog](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2008/12/06/creating-single-post-templates-in-wordpress) which allows you to create single post templates based on category (slug and id), author or tag.

My modified code is below:

```
/**
* Filter the single_template with our custom function
*/
add_filter('single_template', 'my_single_template');

/**
* Single template function which will choose our template
*/
 function my_single_template($single) {
    global $wp_query, $post;

    /**
    * Checks for single template by custom taxonomy 'event_types'
    * Change 'event_types' to whatever your custom taxonomy is called
    * Check by category slug and ID
    */

    //Only change 'event' post type
    if( 'event' != get_post_type($post) )
       return $single;

    //Where your single fiels are located inside your theme
    $single_template_path = get_stylesheet_directory().'/single/';

    //Get the taxonomy terms
    $cats = get_the_terms($post->ID,'event_types');
    if ( !$cats )
       return $single;

    foreach( $cats as $cat ) :

        if(file_exists($single_template_path . '/single-cat-' . $cat->slug . '.php'))
            return $single_template_path . '/single-cat-' . $cat->slug . '.php';

        elseif(file_exists($single_template_path . '/single-cat-' . $cat->term_id . '.php'))
            return $single_template_path  . '/single-cat-' . $cat->term_id . '.php';

    endforeach;
    return $single;

}
```

You would then add your new custom template files into **/wp-content/themes/your-template-name/single**, naming them accordingly.

Using this function you could create a template for a tag called **featured** within a custom taxonomy of **event_types** by creating a file called **single-cat-featured.php**